# Wordpress Permalinks in Nginx 404 error

Tags: wordpress, nginx

There is the following NGINX config:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name <name>;
        client_max_body_size 32m;
        root /home/ulnda/www/wordpress;
        index index.html index.php;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
              include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
              include fastcgi_params;
              fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
              fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/ulnda/www/wordpress$fastcgi_script_name;
              fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE post_max_size=20M;
              fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE upload_max_filesize=20M;
        }
}
```

Site works correctly on domain for example http://somedomain.com. But when I try to open some post with permalink http://somedomain.com/post-about-sea I get 404 error. How can I fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That one should work. Nginx should not return 404 at all in your config.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name <name>;
        client_max_body_size 32m;
        root /home/ulnda/www/wordpress;
        index index.html index.php;

        location / {
              try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {                
              include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
              include fastcgi_params;
              fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
              fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/ulnda/www/wordpress$fastcgi_script_name;
              fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE post_max_size=20M;
              fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE upload_max_filesize=20M;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using Elasticbeanstalk with Amazon Linux 2 then following will be working for you:
create file at given directory:

[image]

in this file add following code:

```
location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

open OS PANEL nginx config and uncomment this fragment

[image: open server nginx config]

```
location / {
                    #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        # Force index.php routing (if not found)
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

            # Force index.php routing (all requests)
            rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 last;
        }
```

if you have it on open server you need to uncomment it
or if it is a linux server, it should be written in the nginx config

don't forget to add this too so that images and fonts work properly

```
# Disable access to backup/config/command/log files
location ~* (?:\.(?:bak|co?nf(ig)?|in[ci]|log|sh|sql|tar|t?gz)|~)$ {
        deny all;
    }

location ~* ^.+\.(?:css(\.map)?|js(\.map)?|jpe?g|png|gif|ico|cur|heic|webp|tiff?|mp3|m4a|aac|ogg|midi?|wav|mp4|mov|webm|mpe?g|avi|ogv|flv|wmv|svgz?|ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff2?)$ {
        expires 1d;
        access_log off;
    }
```